# tintedImageProvider does not provide tint color in Graphic Complication

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch-complication, clockkit

I am trying to create Graphic Complications for my Apple Watch app (namely Graphic Circular) and I've run into some problems. To support both multicolor and tinted watch faces, I use the following code to provide image for my complication:

```
    let graphicCircularTemplate = CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicCircularImage()
    if let tintedImage = UIImage(named: "GraphicCircular"), let fullColorImage = UIImage(named: "GraphicCircularOrange") {
        let tintedImageProvider = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: tintedImage)
        var imageProvider = CLKFullColorImageProvider()
        if #available(watchOSApplicationExtension 6.0, *) {
            imageProvider = CLKFullColorImageProvider(fullColorImage: fullColorImage, tintedImageProvider: tintedImageProvider)
        } else {
            imageProvider = CLKFullColorImageProvider(fullColorImage: fullColorImage)
        }
        graphicCircularTemplate.imageProvider = imageProvider
    }
```

Now my `fullColorImage` is following:
[fullColorImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z02t.png)

Whereas the tinted image of same size is rendered as Template image:
[tintedImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuqMC.png)

In multicolor Infograph watch face the full color image looks as expected:
[multicolor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXK9K.png)

But when I change watch face to a selected tint, my tinted image renders as pure white, and the system tint color does not get applied to it:
[tint color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuxwD.png)

So my question is what am I missing and why does my tintedImageProvider not provide any tint?

Besides, I've noticed that system complications of type Graphic Circular seem to have a slightly grey background which sets them apart in dark watch face environment. I have hardcoded same background color into full color image, but when face switches to tint mode - my complication's background goes completely black. Any ideas on how to achieve this grey background effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, solution came after reiterating through documentation several times - decided to post an answer in case someone else finds this solution as non-obvious as I did:

In Graphic complications that support multicolor watch faces with full-color complication images system tint is only applied to `twoPieceImageForeground` parameter of `tintedImageProvider`. Simply providing a template `onePieceImage` doesn't do the trick.

Creating a two piece image also resolves the second part of my question regarding grey background for image in Graphic Circular complication. To solve this, I've created a plain rectangle image of required complication size, set its background color to black and alpha to 11%. Passing this image as `twoPieceImageBackground` parameter to `tintedImageProvider` creates the needed grey-background effect upon desaturation.

Comment: What's the difference between `fullColorImage` and the `onePieceImage`?  Can you show more details about what you used for the four images?